# Push other views dynamically to below if table view expand/dropdown

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

When I expand the table view section, I want the other views at bottom of the table view to move down dynamically and when collapse it will move up dynamically. Currently expand it will overlap and hide at the views below. May I know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Share some code of what you had tried..

Comment: @VigneshDavins I refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371626/setting-auto-layout-constraints-programmatically-on-two-views-in-viewcontroller . But my UITableView is on the top and UIView is on the bottom, for the UITableView contain section that able to expand and collapse the cell. Wanted to push down the uiview if the cell is expand in table view